# Program making blank output file

Tags: c++, file

So I've been working on a grep like program. That will search a given file and then return all lines with instances of the word you want with the along witht he line number of where it occured. I came up with this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){

// validate the command line info
if( argc < 2 ) {
    cout << "Error: Incorrect number of command line arguments\n"
            "Usage: grep\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

//Declare the arguments of the array
string query = argv[1]; 
string inputFileName = argv[2];
string outFileName = argv [3];
regex reg(query);

// Validate that the file is there and open it
ifstream infile( inputFileName );
if( !infile ) {
    cout << "Error: failed to open <" << inputFileName << ">\n"
            "Check filename, path, or it doesn't exist.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}



 ofstream outFile (outFileName);
 outFile.open( outFileName + ".txt" );
// if( !outFile ){
  //          cout << "Error: failed to create output file at " << outFileName << ".txt\n";
   //         return EXIT_FAILURE;
 //   }


//Create a vector of string to hold each line
vector<string> lines;

//Create a while loop that puts each line into the vector lines
string currentLine = "";
int currentLineNum = 0;

while(getline(infile,currentLine))
{
    lines.push_back( currentLine ); 
            currentLineNum++;
            if( regex_match( query, reg ) )
                    outFile << "Line " << currentLineNum << ": " << currentLine;



}
    outFile.close();
    infile.close();
}
```

When I run it it makes the file but the files end up blank, I'm sure what I'm searching for is in the file, so I imagine I've made a logic error somewhere here. I don't have any experience with making output files, but what I wrote seemed to match the syntax of what I've read. Any advice you guys can give would be greatly appreicated.

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: Just the general Visual Studio debugger, no errors showed.

Comment: No errors showed?  What does that mean?  Clearly there is an error, or your program would be working, right?

Comment: Just that the error list was empty. The program runs fine, it's just that the output file ends up being blank.

Comment: That's not a debugger.  You're talking about error messages from the compiler.  Those aren't going to help you with runtime problems.

Comment: Could you show what you typed into the command line?

Comment: It just typed grep.exe grep.cpp include out.txt
(they were in the same folder)

Comment: I'm confused, shouldn't argv[1] be what you are searching for? `string query = argv[1]; `

Comment: Are you sure your regex is actually matching your input? Which regex are you using?

Comment: Yes Jesse, that's what I'm trying to do anyway :/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by which regex fontanini.

Comment: Do you realize that `argv[1]` is `grep.cpp` and `argv[2]` is `include` according to your comment? (and out.txt becomes `out.txt.txt`)?

Comment: You really should use the visual studio debugger and *step into* your code.  While doing so, inspect each variable to ensure that it contains what you think it should.  (Jesse nailed this).  In other words, put a break point on the very first line after your main() declaration, then use `step over` and `step-into` to go through it line by line.  I think once you inspect the argv parameter you'll see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following two lines, why are you calling constructor and then calling open?

```
ofstream outFile (outFileName); // This does same thing as member function open
outFile.open( outFileName + ".txt" ); // <-- remove this line unnecessary
```

The second line will fail and set failbit, so the stream is in a bad state (also, you have out.txt.txt).